# Is there a way to hide the close button in iOS Safari Full Screen mode?

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, fullscreen

When I switch to full screen mode in iOS Safari on an iPad (the switch happens programmatically, using Javascript), the browser displays a very large and prominent close button at the top left:

[image: iPad with a webpage in full screen]

Is there a programmatic way to hide this button? I need to use that space in my full screen webpage, and it obscures important content.

I am aware that it's possible to create a home screen link to the webpage, which will display it in full screen, but for a variety of reasons, this isn't an ideal solution for me.

Comment: Hi allenrabinovich, have you figured it out? Currently, we have the same issue.

Comment: Stuck on the same thing !! Need a solution !!

Comment: This is so annoying